# How to change text of an element

Tags: python, python-2.5

How can I change just the the text of element `field1.text` without writing the complete file? (python 2.5).

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 
import urllib2
import os

file("c:\Python25\wxTime.xml", 'w')
root = ET.Element("root")  
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc") 
field1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "wxpageTime") 
field1.set("name", "lastUpdate") 
field1.text = "Thu May 10 02:00:00 2012"
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("c:\Python25\wxTime.xml")
```

Comment: Unless the changes to the file are the exact same number of bytes, you have to rewrite the file because it changes the contents of everything after your edit.

Answer (score 1):

You generally can't.  You can reduce the amount of parsing you do, but, as @jdi notes, inserting a single byte modifies every byte after that point, so special a special file format would be required (e.g. database).  XML isn't designed this way, so writing the entire file back is the normal way of making edits like the example you give.

Comment: Good point about the file format. If the goal is to constantly make small changes to a very large file, then a serialized format like xml would not be appropriate. It should be in a database and only serialized as a final delivery format.